# How to create variables based on column names in dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, variables, jupyter

I wanted to create variables in python based on the column names of my dataframe. Not sure if this is possible as I am quite new to Python. Lets say my df looks like this:

```
ID  Date         Name    Counts
1   04/04/2018   JUOM    150
2   05/04/2018   1XMK    22
3   05/04/2018   N2IS    130
```

How could I create one variable where I can reference the Date and the Name columns from this dataframe?

Comment: You don't need to, you can call `df['Date']`, `df['Name']` etc.. why is there a need to assign these to a variable, when you write code like this it should be obvious what you're trying to do

Comment: If you literally want the column names, though, just use `df.columns`.

Comment: My approach was: Lets say I want to declare x as both the Name and the Date column, could I just do:    X = df['Date'], df['Name'] eventhough these columns have different data types?

Answer (score 0):

If you want a variable `x` assigned to the columns `Date` and `Name`, you can subset the data frame with the using `df[['col1','col2',...]]` syntax.    The  outer brackets are the indexer operation of pandas data frame object, while the inner brackets create a list of desired column names.

```
x= df[['Date','Name']]
```

Which returns:

```
         Date  Name
0  04/04/2018  JUOM
1  05/04/2018  1XMK
2  05/04/2018  N2IS
```

If you don't want to have the data in a data frame, you could get the data with [`.values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.values.html) property.

```py
x= df[['Date','Name']].values

array([['04/04/2018', 'JUOM'],
       ['05/04/2018', '1XMK'],
       ['05/04/2018', 'N2IS']], dtype=object)
```

If you are using pandas version 0.24.0, they recommend replacing `.values` with [`to_numpy()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_numpy.html#pandas.DataFrame.to_numpy).

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
var1 = df.columns[0]
var2 = df.columns[1]
```

The result:

> var1 = ID
>
> var2 = Date